# Mongodb insertOne number type and date type without aggregation

Tags: mongodb, typescript

this my script

```
import moment from 'moment';
var date = moment().format();
var value = request.query.value;
collection.insertOne({value: value, date: date});
```

How to convert `value` to `int` and `date` to `date`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that's what you're looking for :

```
collection.insertOne({value: parseInt(value), date: moment().toDate()});
```

Comment: if i'm use `moment().subtract(30, 'days').calendar().split('/').join('-');` could i'm convert to date to?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
import moment from 'moment';
var date = moment().format().toDate();
var value = parseInt(request.query.value);
collection.insertOne({value: value, date: date});
```

plus don't use `var` in TypeScript, they introduced `let` for good reasons,